# Error message during the expr command execution: expr: non-integer argument

Tags: bash, shell, integer, echo

I try to assign two numbers (actually these are the outputs of some remote executed command) to 2 different variables, let say A and B.

When I echo A and B, they show the values:

```
echo $A
809189640755
echo $B
1662145726

sum=`expr $A + expr $B`
expr: non-integer argument
```

I also tried with typeset -i but didn't work. As much as I see, bash doesn't take my variables as integer. What is the easiest way to convert my variable into integer so I can add, subtract, multiply etc. them?

Thanks.

Comment: My issue resolved. So the thing was, remote command I executed also added a return carriage at the end of the number. So I needed to remove it with printf. After that expr  worked.

Answer (score 5):

First, you should not use expr twice. So

```
sum=`expr $A + $B`
```

should work. Another possibility is using pipeline

```
sum=`echo "$A + $B" | bc -l`
```

which should work fine even for multiplications. I am not sure how would it behave if you have too large numbers, but worked for me using your values.

Answer (score 2):

Try in linux bash:

```
A=809189640755
B=1662145726
echo $((A + B))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do

```
expr $A + $B
```

or

```
$(( $A + $B ))
```

Comment: It didn't work. This time a different error message though.
    sum=$(( $A + $B ))
    ")809189640755: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy and paste this code and run. I hope it will be helpful for you.

```
echo "enter first number"
read num1
echo "enter second number"
read num2
echo $((num1 + num2))
```

Save your file as file_name.sh and run it from your terminal